# can't iterate over picamera photos in sub folder

Tags: raspbian, python

Why doesn't take_photo_2() iterate over the photos in the pictures folder like take_photo_1() does in the programs root folder?
it just returns 0 every time and the photo gets overwritten, if i use it in the programs root folder the photos get labelled nicely in order depending on how many files are in the folder just like i want it to.

```
import picamera, os
if not os.path.exists("pictures"):
    os.makedirs("pictures")

def take_photo_1():
    camera = picamera.PiCamera()
    n = str(sum(os.path.isfile(name) for name in os.listdir()))
    camera.capture('img'+n+'.jpg')
    print('take_photo_1 = '+n)
    camera.close()

def take_photo_2():
    camera = picamera.PiCamera()
    n = str(sum(os.path.isfile(name) for name in os.listdir('pictures')))
    camera.capture('pictures/img'+n+'.jpg')
    print('take_photo_2 = '+n)
    camera.close()

for i in range(5):
    #take_photo_1()
    take_photo_2()
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

this worked

```python
n = str(sum(1 for name in os.listdir('pictures')
    if name.endswith('.jpg')))
```

Comment: Why did this work? A better answer would explain the issue for people who have the same one.